# Maximal weight in a heap

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compute the maximal weight in a heap with this function:

```
unsigned int left(unsigned int x)
{return 2*x+1;}

unsigned int right(unsigned int x)
{return 2*x+2;}

unsigned int max_way (unsigned int* feld, int x, int max_size)
{
    if (x > max_size) 
        return 0;
    else 
        return feld[x] + std::max(max_way(feld, left(x), max_size), max_way(feld, right(x), max_size));
}
```

So I try it with a small example:

```
unsigned int feld[] = {3,7,4,2,4,6,8,5,9,3};

std::cout << max_way(feld, 0, 10);
```

The result is 134514494. That's a bit to big!

Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't look like any heap I've ever heard of.  Is the intended result 21?  Because emulating in my head gives 21.

Comment: Looked like a heap to me. That's how I answered his question. A heap is any structure that has the heap property: if B is a child node of A, then key(A) ≥ key(B). Here the key is the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (x > max_size)
```

should be

```
if (x >= max_size)
```

C++ arrays go from 0 .. max-1.

Answer (score 0):

You might try whit

```
if(x >= max_size)
```